# Dropping A Table Using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This presents an error of:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Testingwithdynamicsql'.

Now why is that, if I print my sql it appears valid to me, what do I alter to make it work?

```
Declare @tablename varchar(500), @sql varchar(max)
set @tablename = 'Testingwithdynamicsql'
set @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID('+@tablename+', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE ' + @tablename + ' '
Print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: EXEC may not operate on the same database the rest of your code is; try adding a `USE [DatabaseName]` as the first statement in your `@sql` variable.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ - still produces same error adding the Use statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @tablename needs to be quoted

```
Declare @tablename varchar(500), @sql varchar(max)
set @tablename = 'Testingwithdynamicsql'
set @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID('''+@tablename+''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE ' + @tablename + ' '
Print @sql
```